# pgagent on centos 64bit

Tags: postgresql, centos, centos6, pgagent

I am trying to install pgAgent for two straight day on a centOS 6.2 64bit.
I have been trying to compile it from source without success because I could not manage to compile wxWidgets.
I have been trying to use a precompiled version but was unsuccessful because of missing libraries :

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00f6c000)
libssl.so.0 => not found
libcrypto.so.0 => not found
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00a84000)
libz.so.1 => not found
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x0063f000)
libstdc++.so.6 => not found
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x0047d000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => not found
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00110000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x0012b000)
libfreebl3.so => /lib/libfreebl3.so (0x00c85000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00819000)
```

I am little confused on the approach I should take to get out of those quick sands ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to compile wxWidgets; just `yum install wxGTK-devel` to get both the runtime library and the C header files.

As for the precompiled version - *which* precompiled version? From where? Installed how?