# pgagent centos 6.2

Tags: postgresql, centos, pgagent

I have successfully [compiled pgagent from source on a CentOS 6.2 server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298247/pgagent-on-centos-64bit).

When I try to launch pgagent with the following command :

```
/usr/bin/pgagent -l 2 hostaddr=serveur.com dbname=postgres user=postgres
```

I get the following error messages :

```
DEBUG:      user         : postgres
DEBUG:      port         : 0
DEBUG:      host         : server.com
DEBUG:      dbname       : postgres
DEBUG:      password     : 
DEBUG:      conn timeout : 0
DEBUG: Connection Information:
DEBUG:      user         : postgres
DEBUG:      port         : 0
DEBUG:      host         : server.com
DEBUG:      dbname       : postgres
DEBUG:      password     : 
DEBUG:      conn timeout : 0
DEBUG: Creating DB connection: user=postgres host=server.com dbname=postgres
DEBUG: Database sanity check
DEBUG: Clearing zombies
WARNING: Query error: ERROR:  could not extend file "base/12870/12615": No space left on device
HINT:  Check free disk space.

WARNING: Query error: ERROR:  relation "pga_tmp_zombies" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO pga_tmp_zombies (jagpid) SELECT jagpid   FROM pg...
                    ^

WARNING: Query error: ERROR:  table "pga_tmp_zombies" does not exist

WARNING: Query error: ERROR:  could not extend file "base/12870/17167": No space left on device
HINT:  Check free disk space.

WARNING: Couldn't create the primary connection (attempt 1): ERROR:  could not extend file "base/12870/17167": No space left on device
HINT:  Check free disk space.
DEBUG: Clearing all connections
DEBUG: Connection stats: total - 1, free - 0, deleted - 1
```

Any idea of the source of the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WARNING: Query error: ERROR:  could not extend file "base/12870/12615": No space left on device
HINT:  Check free disk space.
```

You're out of disk space, or (rather unlikely) a disk access quota limit has been hit for the database user. It's also possible you've run out of inodes on the file system for some platforms and file systems. Check `df`.